# Cocos2d-x Parallax Infinite Scrolling Error

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, parallax

Good day,

I am writing a code that will infinitely scroll that is parallax, but I can't seem to do this correctly.

here is my code:

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();


auto mountainSprite = Sprite::create( "Mountain.png" );
auto treesSprite = Sprite::create( "Trees.png" );
auto housesSprite = Sprite::create( "Houses.png" );

auto paraNode = ParallaxNode::create();
paraNode->addChild(mountainSprite, -1, Vec2(0.4f,0.5f), Vec2(800,480));

paraNode->addChild(treesSprite, 1, Vec2(2.2f,1.0f), Vec2(800,480));

paraNode->addChild(housesSprite, 2, Vec2(3.0f,2.5f), Vec2(800,480));
```

**The result is a black blank screen.**

Also, I have this follow-up questions:

1. Can I replace the "Vec2(float xx, float yy)" with "Point(x,y)" here? Because it seems not of cocos2d-x version 3.6? what is "ccp(x,y)"? which is better Vec2, Point or ccp?
2. What is "positionOffset" that this "addChild (Node *child, int z, const Vec2 &parallaxRatio, const Vec2 &positionOffset)", talks about? from link: [ParallaxNode Class Reference](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.6/d0/dd1/classcocos2d_1_1_parallax_node.html)
3. I tried this tutorial: [Raywenderlich Parallax Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/cocos2d-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game), but don't understand it, can someone explain it to me? The things that confused me is what are those "**CCSprite**" is this the same as "Sprite", why?, "**CCParallaxNode**" is this the same as "ParallaxNode", why?

and what is "**[self addChild:*_backgroundNode z:-1*]**" is this the
    same as "**this->addChild(node)**"?

Any answer or suggestion to any questions are appreciated. **Thanks :D**

Answer (score 1):

```
this->addChild(paraNode);
```

Try this.